# Seleccionar todos los campos de un mat-select multiple Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

cuento con un campo de selección múltiple y estoy intentando que todos los campos estén seleccionados cuando se produce la carga del componente, he intentado con los atributos selected y checked dentro del mat-option pero no me he conseguido resolver nada. A continuación os adjunto mi codigo.

HTML

```
 <mat-form-field class="MR15">
     <mat-select multiple type="text" placeholder="Días" formControlName="dias">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let dia of listDia" [value]='dia.codigo'>{{dia.descripcion}}</mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS

```
public listDia: CodigoDescripcion[] = [
  {codigo: 'L', descripcion: 'Lunes'},
  {codigo: 'M', descripcion: 'Martes'},
  {codigo: 'X', descripcion: 'Miércoles'},
  {codigo: 'J', descripcion: 'Jueves'},
  {codigo: 'V', descripcion: 'Viernes'},
  {codigo: 'S', descripcion: 'Sábado'},
  {codigo: 'D', descripcion: 'Domingo'},
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añade el valor inicial desde el controlador. Por ejemplo:

```
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.formulario.controls[dias].setValue([
    {codigo: 'L', descripcion: 'Lunes'},
    {codigo: 'M', descripcion: 'Martes'},
    {codigo: 'X', descripcion: 'Miércoles'}
  ]);
}
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando aquí: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-multiselect-pawer13

Answer (score 0):

simplemente pasale el objeto `listDia` al valor por defecto al crear el form

`dias: new FormControl(listDia, [])`