# select por default dinámico con angular material

Tags: angular, material

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Roles</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="roles" multiple >
        <mat-option  value="role.rolName"  selected="selected.rolName" *ngFor="let role of roleList">
            {{role.rolName}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**método que trae los datos del backend este método se lanza cuando doy clic en la opcion editar de mi tabla**

```
getUserById(userId: number) {
    console.log('userId->', userId);
    return this.userService.getUserById(userId).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log('controller->', response.roles[0].rolName);
      this.userAdminFormService.fillForm(response);
    });
  }
```

*estoy utilizando los formularios reactivos formBuilder formGroup formControlName
lo que quiero es que cuando presione sobre el botón editar en el formulario aparezca seleccionado por default en el select los roles de usuario, primero se cargan por default todos los roles que un usuario podría tener pero si quiero actualizar a un usuario registrado quisiera que sus roles aparezca seleccionado por default recordales que estoy trabajando con select multiple*

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserAdminFormService {

  public fb = new FormBuilder;

  constructor() { }

  public form = this.fb.group({
    userId: [''],
    name: ['', [Validators.required]],
    lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    userName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    userPassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
    userEnabled: ['', [Validators.required]],
    userEmail: ['', [Validators.required]],
    roles: ['', [Validators.required]]

  });

  public initializeForm() {
    this.form.setValue({
      userId: [''],
      name: [''],
      lastName: [''],
      userName: [''],
      userPassword: [''],
      userEnabled: [''],
      userEmail: [''],
      roles: ['']
    });
    this.form.markAsUntouched();
  }

  public fillForm(data: any) {
   
    this.form.setValue({
      userId: [data.userId],
      name: [data.name],
      lastName: [data.lastName],
      userName: [data.userName],
      userPassword: [data.userPassword],
      userEnabled: [data.userEnabled],
      userEmail: [data.userEmail],
      roles: [data.roles]
    });
  }
```

**el resto de los datos ya se me carga pero no logro hacer que los roles aparezcan seleccionados alguna idea o documentacion que me puedan bridar gracias**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como te aparece los datos del response en la parte de roles en consola y en el <mat-option  value="role.rolName" ahí no seteas el "id" del rol en lugar del name?

Comment: lastName: "gamboa"
name: "vladimir"
roles: Array(2)
0: {rolId: 1, rolName: "ROLE_USER"}
1: {rolId: 2, rolName: "ROLE_ADMIN"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
userAttempts: null
userEmail: "vladimir@gamboa.com"
userEnabled: true
userId: 2
userName: "vladimir"

Comment: saludos @JeffersonCuji esto me devuelve el response

Comment: bueno lo que pensé hacer fue esto  selected: Rol[] = []; este atributo lo cargo cuando me suscribo  this.selected = response.roles; el response me trae sus roles del usuario a actualizar

Comment: quizá podrías a ese response filtrarle con el listado de roles antes de setear los valores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*al fin pude encontrar la solución, publico la respuesta para algunos que talvez estén buscando lo mismo y si tienen otras ideas espero que lo publiquen*

```
 public fillForm(data: any) {
    let selected: any[] = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < data.roles.length; index++) {
      selected.push(data.roles[index].rolName);
    }
    this.form.setValue({
      userId: [data.userId],
      name: [data.name],
      lastName: [data.lastName],
      userName: [data.userName],
      userPassword: [data.userPassword],
      userEnabled: [data.userEnabled],
      userEmail: [data.userEmail],
      roles: [...selected]
    });
```

*en el html*

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width">
            <mat-label>Roles</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="roles" multiple>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roleList;let i=index" [value]="role.rolName">
                    {{role.rolName}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: esta respuesta me dio la idea https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299574/seleccionar-todos-los-campos-de-un-mat-select-multiple-angular-7